# Jar файл не видит изображение

Tags: java, файлы, изображения, jar

Написал простенький проект, в котором есть изображения.
После чего заархивировал его в `jar` файл с помощью `IntelliJ IDEA`.
При запуске файла все работает кроме картинок, их просто нету.
Картинки лежат в `src` папке. Путь задаю вот так:

```java
Image img = new ImageIcon("src/name.png"). getImage();
```

Имена картинок в `jar` файле не изменялись.

Comment: Во-первых, с файлами упакованными в jar надо работать не как с файлами, а как с [ресурсами](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/lang/resources.html). Во-вторых, в jar не упаковывается каталог src.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы ищете картинку снаружи jar. Что бы получить ресурс внутри jar нужно использовать конструкцию getResource.

```
ClassInSrcFolder.getClass.getResource("name.png");
```

Comment: А как это переписать в соответствие с Вашим вариантом? `btn_add_to_list.setIcon(new ImageIcon("lib\\icons\\create.png"));`

Comment: Не очень понятно, что у вас за структура, должна быть папка, обычно res или resource, которая промаркирована ресурсной, тогда после сборки в jar ее содержимое будет внутри, у вас суда по всему картинки остаются снаружи.

Answer (score 2):

После архивирования папки `src` больше нет. Рисунки надо доставать с пути. Например

```
Image img = new ImageIcon(Frame1.class.getResource("name.png"))
            .getImage();
```